# Importing data using Firebase Console would trigger too many Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-console

I've run into a problem while trying to update the schema for my database. My plan was to export the data, use a local script to modify it, then import the modified data to overwrite the database.

The problem is Firebase console won't allow me to import the new data because it contains about 10,000 keys, each of which would trigger a Firebase Function (actually, a few functions), and I assume it's over some internal limit.

How would you modify a large number of paths like this?

My alternate ideas:

1. Temporarily remove the Firebase Functions that this operation would trigger. I don't like this because (I assume) it removes the log/execution history for the functions
2. Use firebase-admin to modify each path. This will use a lot of database bandwidth, and I believe it will trigger the functions anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to temporarily disable Cloud Functions, nor to tell to bypass triggering of Cloud Functions on a certain import or API call.

The only way to solve this would be to temporarily remove the function, import the data, and then re-enable the function.

This is a common use-case that would be great if it'd be supported in a more integrated way, so I'd recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Someone else (on another site) pointed out that [the trigger limit can be disabled](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits). I'll try doing that.

Comment: I'll also submit a feature request; temporarily disabling a function seems like it would be very useful in certain situations, I'm surprised Cloud Functions doesn't support it.

Comment: Cool. I didn't know that, so thanks for sharing. It'd still trigger for each write, which in some cases I'd like to prevent. Then again: I think it may simply be a "fear of paying for invocations". Maybe I should actually do the math on that, and figure out it's the wrong type of thing to spend time on.